# Cartopy barbs not working properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot 250 hPa geopotential heights, 1000 hPa precipitable water, and 250 hPa winds over a north Pacific projection. When trying to use barbs, I don't get an error, but the barbs don't physically show up on the map. I think it may have something to do with the projection of my data onto the cartopy projection, but I'm quite new to cartopy and don't quite understand what is happening. If someone notices that my projections in general are screwed up, I wouldn't mind some direction. Thanks!

```
def plotMap():

    proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-165, central_latitude=30, standard_parallels=[53])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))   

    ax.set_extent([235 ,160 , 5, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())    
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='0.9') 
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.9)  
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, zorder=10)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=10)

    states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',  
    name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines', scale='50m', facecolor='none')

    ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='gray', zorder=10)

    ax.gridlines(xlocs=np.arange(0,361,20), ylocs=np.arange(-80,90,20)) 

    return fig, ax

fig, ax = plotMap()




hght_levels = np.arange(9500,11250,250)
hght_contour=ax.contour(lon, lat, g, colors='k', levels=hght_levels, 
linewidths=1, zorder=3, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())

wind_levels = np.arange(0, 110, 10)
wind_contour = ax.contour(lon, lat, wind, levels = wind_levels, 
linewidths=5, zorder=0.8, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())

pwat_levels = np.linspace(0, 50, 9)
pwat_contour = ax.contourf(lon, lat, pwat, levels = pwat_levels,  
                       cmap=plt.cm.plasma, zorder=1.0, transform = 
ccrs.PlateCarree())
cb = plt.colorbar(pwat_contour, shrink=0.5)
cb.set_ticklabels(pwat_levels)

urel = u.values*1.944
vrel = v.values*1.944
ax.barbs(lon, lat, urel, vrel, regrid_shape=12 transform=ccrs.LambertConformal())

plt.clabel(hght_contour, hght_levels, zorder=20, inline=1,inline_spacing=3, 
fmt='%1i', fontsize=12)


fig
```

[The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhHca.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your projection on the call `barbs` gives the `transform` argument as `LambertConformal()`, but it looks like you're passing in latitude and longitude values for position. Change `transform` to `PlateCarree()`, as you use in the other plot methods.

Comment: This works, but it plots so many barbs that you can't see the data. I tried using regrid_shape and set it to various values, but I keep getting an error about :  QH6019 qhull input error: can not scale last coordinate.  Input is cocircular  or cospherical.

Comment: I'm not sure about `regrid_shape`, but my usual solution is: `ax.barbs(lon[::5, ::5], lat[::5, ::5], urel[::5, ::5], vrel[::5, ::5], transform=ccrs.LambertConformal())`

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion and get the error of: too many indices for array. Not sure why this is so difficult, doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: If it's 1D arrays for lon/lat, then you should do this instead: `ax.barbs(lon[::5], lat[::5], urel[::5, ::5], vrel[::5, ::5], transform=ccrs.LambertConformal())`. You'll have to look at the details of your data layout (1D, 2D, etc.) to get it right.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Would you mind explaining exactly what this is doing? I'm not super familiar with coding yet, as I'm sure you're aware.

Comment: That's using Python slicing syntax, but using the default start and stop (which includes every element), with the 5 telling it to skip every 5th point. For `urel` and `vrel`, it's doing that for both dimensions. You can find information on doing this with numpy here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @DopplerShift Thanks for your great answer in this. In my case I have converted latitude and longitude into 1D, whereas my u wind and v wind are 2D. Hence the following code worked well.
```ax.barbs(imr.longitude[::5],imr.latitude[::5], uwind[::5, ::5], vwind[::5, ::5], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())```